# cannot get outside variable value in callback function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Now I have a controller and set some function like following. I want to get the variable data2 in callback function. But now it's undefined.

```js
var searchApp = angular.module('reveal.searchUI');

searchApp.controller('SearchController', ['$rootScope','$scope','$q','$http','$timeout','$window',
    '$i18next', '$filter','$sanitize', '$cookies',
    'emcui.EventBus','RemoteUrl',"Reveal","Cache","AUTH_EVENTS",
    function($rootScope, $scope, $q, $http, $timeout, $window, $i18next,
             $filter, $sanitize,$cookies, eventBus,remoteUrlProvider, reveal,
             cache, AUTH_EVENTS){
        var self = this;
        var data1 = "data1";
        this.testing = function(){
          var data2 = "data2";
          setTimeout(function(){
            //need to get the variable data2
            },1000);
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code to suggest that you would not be able to access that variable. Are you sure ```.testing``` is actually running?

Comment: With the AngularJS framework, the code should be using the [$timeout service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) instead of the raw `setTimeout`. What is curious is that the controller injects `$timeout` but doesn't use it. Can you explain this?

Comment: I try to run it by self.testing(). From debugging, the variable cannot be accessed.

Comment: Hi, I try to replace setTimeout with $timeout, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 2):

The code *is* able to access `data2` in the callback.

**Ensure that the example actually reproduces the problem!** If you inadvertently fixed the problem while composing the example but didn't test it again, you'd want to know that before asking someone else to help.

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/uAnY1HjtpjMXrApMyyDC?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller('SearchController', [
    function(){
        var self = this;
        var data1 = "data1";
        this.testing = function(){
          var data2 = "data2";
          setTimeout(function(){
            //need to get the variable data2
            console.log(data2);
            },1000);
        };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="SearchController as vm">
    <button ng-click="vm.testing()">Click me</button>
  </body>
```